# String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter

I was working on flutter and when i try to read json file from lists its throwing String' is not a subtype of type 'int'. How Can I parse this JSON data ?? I was working on flutter and when i try to read json file from lists its throwing String' is not a subtype of type 'int'. How Can I parse this JSON data ??

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<CartResponse> cartResponseFromJson(String str) => 
List<CartResponse>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => CartResponse.fromJson(x)));

String cartResponseToJson(List<CartResponse> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => 
x.toJson())));

class CartResponse {
CartResponse({
this.name,
this.owner_id,
this.cart_items,
});

String name;
int owner_id;
List<CartItem> cart_items;

factory CartResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartResponse(
name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
owner_id: json["owner_id"] == null ? null : json["owner_id"],
cart_items: json["cart_items"] == null ? null : List<CartItem>.from(json["cart_items"].map((x) => 
CartItem.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"name": name == null ? null : name,
"owner_id": owner_id == null ? null : owner_id,
"cart_items": cart_items == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(cart_items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}

class CartItem {
CartItem({
this.id,
this.owner_id,
this.user_id,
this.product_id,
this.product_name,
this.product_thumbnail_image,
this.variation,
this.currency_symbol,
this.price,
this.tax,
this.shipping_cost,
this.quantity,
this.lower_limit,
this.upper_limit,
});

int id;
int owner_id;
int user_id;
int product_id;
String product_name;
String product_thumbnail_image;
String variation;
double price;
String currency_symbol;
double tax;
double shipping_cost;
int quantity;
int lower_limit;
int upper_limit;

factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartItem(
id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
owner_id: json["owner_id"] == null ? null : json["owner_id"],
user_id: json["user_id"] == null ? null : json["user_id"],
product_id: json["product_id"] == null ? null : json["product_id"],
product_name: json["product_name"] == null ? null : json["product_name"],
product_thumbnail_image: json["product_thumbnail_image"] == null ? null : 
json["product_thumbnail_image"],
variation: json["variation"] == null ? null : json["variation"],
price: json["price"] == null ? null : json["price"].toDouble(),
currency_symbol: json["currency_symbol"] == null ? null : json["currency_symbol"],
tax: json["tax"] == null ? null : json["tax"].toDouble(),
shipping_cost: json["shipping_cost"] == null ? null : json["shipping_cost"].toDouble(),
quantity: json["quantity"] == null ? null : json["quantity"],
lower_limit: json["lower_limit"] == null ? null : json["lower_limit"],
upper_limit: json["upper_limit"] == null ? null : json["upper_limit"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"id": id == null ? null : id,
"owner_id": owner_id == null ? null : owner_id,
"user_id": user_id == null ? null : user_id,
"product_id": product_id == null ? null : product_id,
"product_name": product_name == null ? null : product_name,
"product_thumbnail_image": product_thumbnail_image == null ? null : product_thumbnail_image,
"variation": variation == null ? null : variation,
"price": price == null ? null : price,
"currency_symbol": currency_symbol == null ? null : currency_symbol,
"tax": tax == null ? null : tax,
"shipping_cost": shipping_cost == null ? null : shipping_cost,
"quantity": quantity == null ? null : quantity,
"lower_limit": lower_limit == null ? null : lower_limit,
"upper_limit": upper_limit == null ? null : upper_limit,
};
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample JSON data you use

Comment: it fetch from database

Comment: check your response from postman and provide sample of json. Try changing int to var, this may work but its not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int.tryParse(json['owner_id']) ?? -1
```

Comment: error changed to 'int' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Comment: use exactly this line:
owner_id: int.tryParse(json['owner_id']),

Comment: the documentation says => To parse this JSON data, do, final cartResponse = cartResponseFromJson(jsonString); How can i do this??

Comment: how should I know that??
if you want help, then you have to describe your problem better or you have to share your stacktrace. And if you're talking about a documentation, we need to know which one... Could you provide a link?